# Появление другого наполнения при выборе пункта

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Делаю калькулятор окон. Вот для того, чтобы он был красив и функционален, хочу сделать так:

На первом этапе выбираем тип окна (Окна, балконы, лоджии) - это можно все сделать в виде картинок, но это не суть. И нужно, чтобы в зависимости от того, что выбрано, подгружался свой калькулятор - для окон один, для балконов и лоджий свои.

Подскажите как функцию load использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.class-name').click(function() { $('.calculator').html('<div class="new-calculator">blablabla</div>'); })
```

Вместо blablabla код другого калькулятора. Или же можно код каждого калькулятора добавить в отдельный файл и подгружать его оттуда функцией - .load('element.html');

Comment: если воспользоваться функцией load, то адрес страницы меняться не будет? Это аналогично include в php?

Comment: > если воспользоваться функцией load, то адрес страницы меняться не будет?

да

> Это аналогично include в php?

нет